# How can I easy attach a 3d text to a 3d gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Now what I did is adding the 3d text GameObject > 3D Object > 3D Text to be a child of the 3d object and then dragging the 3d text more or less to be as much as close to the 3d object.

But is there a way to stick/attach automatic the text to one of the gameobject sides ?

Btw: What is the warning on the bottom meaning ? How can I fix it ?

[image: £d Text]

Comment: Do you need to "attach" object (3D Text) to another object's side in the editor or at runtime?

Comment: @Nitro557 Could be later maybe also in editor but the main goal is to attach it in runtime.

Comment: I just did it. Solution soon.